# Keras: loss keeps increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

Code:

```
import keras
import numpy as np

x = []
y = []

for i in range(1000):
    x.append((i/10.0))
    y.append(2.71828 ** (i/10.0))

x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
x = x.T
y = y.T

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001))
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)

tx = [0.0, 1.0, 10.0]
tx = np.asarray(tx)
tx = tx.T

print(model.predict(tx))
```

This is a very simple neural net which intends to map e^x. Its my first time using keras and when I run it, the loss keeps increasing to infinity. Instead it should decrease.

Answer (score 8):

If a loss increases to infinity it is a sign that the learning rate is too high. The problem with fitting e^x, where x = 100 as in your case is that the difference in values will be very large. Therefore the gradient is going to be very large and the updates are going to be just as large, depending on your learning rate. However if your learning rate is very small, the network will be dominated by those large updates. That is one of the reasons why values are normalized in deep learning.

One quick solution would be to just use the first 100 values or decrease your step size.

Comment: I've already tried decreasing the learning rate. I've tried as low as 10^-15 but loss still increases.

Comment: 10^-15 is nothing compared to e^100. Your network will initially output something like 200 or so for that value and you say it should be 10^40. The gradient is going to be 2 * this value. Therefore your parameters are getting updated to some ridiculously large values and then you have problems with numerical instability and nans.

Comment: Okay.. so, I'm rookie so how do I normalize my values to avoid this explosion?

Comment: In deep learning you could do a dataset normalization so you calculate the mean and the stddev of your dataset and then subtract your mean and then the stddev from every datapoint. But I would suggest not using those high values in the first place. For training purposes its good enough to use values from e^0 to e^5. It is also way easier to plot a function like this. I can advise you to take a look at your dataset, e.g. plot its values and maybe the gradient. Then you will see that the updates do not make that much sense.